# How to rearrange numbers in array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, numbers

My numbers is this;

```
$input =array{1,2,3,4,6,8,11}
```

I want to make it;

```
$input =array{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

*changing 6 to 5, 8 to 6 and 11 to 7

I hope you are getting what I am trying to say.

Comment: Then go for it! Have you tried something?

Comment: `$input = range(1, count($input));`

Comment: @MarkBaker Don't seems like OP comes back or response to any answer/comments

Comment: What actually I am trying to do is like this:      array( 31  => a, -1 => b, 30 => c,)     to this:        array( 1  => b, 2 => c, 3 => a)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$input = array_values($input);
```

`array_values()` returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

to make it a base one array:

```
array_unshift($input, "dummy");
unset($input[0]);
```

**EDIT:**
I see, I may have misunderstood the question. try this:

```
$input_ = array();

for($i=1; $i <= count($input); $i++) {
$input_[] = $i;
}

print_r($input_);
```

Comment: This is to reindex an array not what OP wants

Comment: I believe it is exactly what he wants, did I misread his example?

Comment: What actually I am trying to do is like this:      array( 31  => a, -1 => b, 30 => c,)     to this:        array( 1  => b, 2 => c, 3 => a)

Comment: Could you explain why and the source of the data? There's probably a much more straight forward solution available.

Answer (score 1):

try this

**EDIT**

```
 $input =array(1,2,3,4,6,8,11);

for($i=0;$i<count($input);$i++)
{
    if($input[$i]!=($i+1))
    {
        $input[$i] = ($i+1);
    }
}
print_r($input);
```

Comment: I have deleted my post as it looks very similar to your ones.

Comment: @Saif you dont need to... both were little different though... you were changing all key values and in mine i am just chaning values which are not matched

Comment: But  this one more appropriate than mine

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd request and i'm not sure what the logic or reasoning behind it is. Nethertheless just flipping the array keys with the array values will produce this result. We insert an empty value and then remove it to give the index start of 1.

```
$input = array(1,2,3,4,6,8,11);
array_unshift($input,"");
unset($input[0]);
$flipped = array_flip($input);
```

Comment: What actually I am trying to do is like this:      array( 31  => a, -1 => b, 30 => c,)     to this:        array( 1  => b, 2 => c, 3 => a)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$input =array(1,2,3,4,6,8,11);
array_push($input,1);
$res = array_keys(array_values($input));
$data = array_shift($res);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

result array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
)
```

Comment: What actually I am trying to do is like this:      array( 31  => a, -1 => b, 30 => c,)     to this:        array( 1  => b, 2 => c, 3 => a)

Comment: $numbers = array( 31 => a, -1 => b, 30 => c);
ksort($numbers);
$res = array_values($numbers);
print_r($res);